# Why keys instead of just values in binary search trees?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

Why do the operations on BSTs (search, delete, get, min, max, floor, ceiling, rank, etc.) make use of keys rather than values? Would we not be able to store `Comparable` values and operate on them instead? What is the benefit of having keys in a BST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely could build a BST that just uses values and not keys. Generally speaking, when talking about data structures, we tend to use terms that are independent of any particular programming language. For example, C++ doesn't have a `Comparable` interface, and the way you'd get comparisons working on types in C looks totally different than in Java.

The idea of "keys" and "values" is to discuss at a high level the idea that the tree stores a set of things (the keys) that are sorted, and each key has an associated value. The way that you actually implement that might be to have a single `Comparable` object that stores both a key and a value, or just a key with no value. From the vantage point of Theoryland, though, it's nice to be able to talk about the concepts separately so that we can reason about how the data structure works at a high level without worrying too much about the implementation details behind the individual things being stored.